# Why is oReq used as the object name for a new http request object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, terminology

I've searched here and on MDN. I have yet to find an answer. It seems trivial and it looks like you can name the object anything such as `var blahBlah = new XMLHttpRequest();` then proceed with the rest of the code.

I just want to make sure I understand what I am doing.

Comment: What source are you referring to? Surely you've found code on the internet that shows different variable names than `oReq`. You're right - the name of the variable is completely irrelevant and unimportant.

Comment: The actual name of a variable is only of importance to the developer / the reader of the source code. It is of no relevance to the actual execution of the code.

Comment: I am using the SheetJS js-xlsx library to parse Excel sheets and one method they have listed in the documentation to get the file is by XMLHttpRequest. I wanted to know why oReq was being used, then I found that a lot of people's code uses oReq as the name of the XMLHttpRequest object. That made me wonder if there was a special reason for it.

Comment: maybe its short for "object request" .. hungarian notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`oReq`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) here is just the name of the variable and you can call it whatever you like (including `blahBlah`).

On [a different page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) they've called the variable `httpRequest` instead.

On W3C's [XMLHttpRequest Level 1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) they name the variable `client` throughout.

As [Felix Kling commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296150/why-is-oreq-used-as-the-object-name-for-a-new-http-request-object-in-javascript/31296294#comment50583398_31296150) on your question:

> The actual name of a variable is only of importance to the developer / the reader of the source code. It is of no relevance to the actual execution of the code.